# Type definition: Pointer vs Value

Tags: go, types

I'm new in Go and would like to **extend** `treemap.Map` from `GoDS` project.

I started by defining a type alias for `treemap.Map`:

```golang
import "github.com/emirpasic/gods/maps/treemap"

type Index = treemap.Map

func (idx Index) Add(k int, v int) {
    idx.Put(k, v)
}
```

Getting the following compilation error: `cannot define new methods on non-local type treemap.Map`

After that, I changed the type alias to a type definition:

```golang
type IndexType treemap.Map 

func (idx IndexType) Add(k int, v int) {
    idx.Put(k, v)
}
```

Now I started getting the following error: `idx.Put undefined (type IndexType has no field or method Put)`.

The initial thought was that I'm getting this error because `Put` is defined for a pointer type and based on this naive assumption  I changed the receiver type:

```golang
func (idx *IndexType) Add(k int, v int) {
    idx.Put(k, v)
}
```

Doesn't compile: `idx.Put undefined (type *IndexType has no field or method Put)`

Tried another way around:

```golang
func (idx IndexType) Add(k int, v int) {
    (&idx).Put(k, v)
}
```

Doesn't compile: `(&idx).Put undefined (type *IndexType has no field or method Put)`

I also tried `type IndexType *treemap.Map` but it did not lead me to anything. 
I spent a few hours trying to understand the logic behind those errors but I failed to find any logical explanation.

I know that I can achieve my goal by using `embedding`:

```golang
import "github.com/emirpasic/gods/maps/treemap"

type IndexType struct {
    *treemap.Map
}

func (idx IndexType) Add(k int, v int) {
    idx.Put(k, v)
}
```

The code above compiles.

However, the question I still have: is it possible to extend the type like `treemap.Map` using `type` operator? gol

Comment: No. You cannot extend types in Go. There is no inheritance in Go. Go is not an object-oriented language, it does not have classes or type hierarchies.

Comment: @Adrian however it works with buit-in type map: https://play.golang.org/p/TohwjugP2iQ

Comment: No different than with your second example; as you've shown yourself, you can define a type and define methods on it. If the underlying type had methods, they would not be accessible from the new type.

Comment: @Adrian ok, then what is the purpose of having this form to define types: `type T1 T2` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - that's the only form to define types in Go, are you asking what the point of types is?

Comment: @Adrian what's the point of having the following construction:

`type SomeType1 SomeType2 ` ?

Comment: See my answer, perhaps it will shed some light.

Comment: @Adrian `There is no inheritance in Go` not entirely true since go has embedding, functions from embedded struct get promoted to enclosing struct

Comment: Which is embedding, not inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated perhaps too plainly in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type declaration.

That means when you define a type like `type Foo Bar` where `Foo` and `Bar` are both named types, the *underlying type* of `Foo` is **not** `Bar`. It is `Bar`'s *underlying type*. If `Bar` is a `struct`, then `Foo`'s underlying type is the *struct literal* that defines `Bar` (or the type `Bar` is based on, and so on). Since a struct literal has no methods, neither does `Foo`; the methods defined on `Bar` are defined *only* on `Bar`, not on the struct literal which might be its underlying type. So `Foo` has no methods.

`Foo` also has no "parent type"; it has *only* its underlying type, which is the struct literal. There is no type hierarchy; you can `type Foo Bar`, then `type Baz Foo`, then `type Qux Baz`, and none of these have any "knowledge" of one another; they simply all share an underlying type, which is just a memory layout for storing the type's data.

Comment: Ok , looks like I got it, when you define a struct like this :

`type Bar struct {}`

The Bar's underlying type is _struct literal_

And when you write `type Foo Bar` then the underlying type of `Foo` is `struct literal`
that doesn't have methods defined on `Bar`

Comment: It explains why my code doesn't compile, but I'm still curious when I should use this construction

Comment: When you want a new type with the same underlying type.